# Why won't my master table column increment in my trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I need to create a trigger that will keep track of the number of times a movie is rented from a business like Blockbuster.  I need a separate trigger for an insert, a delete and an update.

The column that tracks this number of times rented is called num_rentals and has a datatype of int.  This column is part of the **Movies** table which has *movie_id (pk*), movie_title, release_year, movie_description, and num_rentals.  The **customer_rentals** table has item_rental_id(pk), *movie_id(fk*), customer_id.

I searched and found a similar thread here for this and tried using the supplied answer, but to no avail.  I executed the following string without any errors but I saw no change in the num_rentals column when I inserted data into either the Movie or the Customer_rentals table. What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_num_rented_insert ON dbo.customer_rentals
    FOR INSERT
AS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE  m
        SET     num_rentals = num_rentals + 1
        FROM    dbo.movies AS m
                INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON m.movie_id = i.movie_id ;
        END
```

I added the num_rentals field to the table later and I also need to know how to initialize the field value to zero for all records currently in the Movies table.

I want to understand this as much as I want the answer so assistance is greatly appreciated. I read that there may be more efficient ways to manage this type of data, but this is the way my instructor wants it.     Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you need a trigger for this? Can't you calculate the count from `dbo.customer_rentals`? What problem are you solving by storing this count twice?

Comment: I believe it is simply an exercise to simply write a trigger.  My problem is we have not done any before and I'm just not getting it.

Comment: Actually @Steve, I think you got it pretty well, you were just not seeing the null column issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem is null num_rental column.  So you're adding null to 1, resulting in null.

Personally, I'd set the num_rentals column to non-nullable with a default of zero, but assuming you can't do that, use isnull().

Like so

```
alter TRIGGER dbo.tr_num_rented_insert ON dbo.customer_rentals
    FOR INSERT
AS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE  m
        SET     num_rentals = isnull(num_rentals,0) + 1
        FROM    dbo.movies AS m
                INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON m.movie_id = i.movie_id ;
    END
```

However, even though this works, there is a problem with it; if you add multiple rows to customer_rentals, it's only going to increment by one.  Personally, I'd change the trigger to account for that.

Like this

```
alter TRIGGER dbo.tr_num_rented_insert ON dbo.customer_rentals
    FOR INSERT
AS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE  m
        SET     num_rentals = isnull(num_rentals,0) + (select COUNT(*) from inserted where movie_id = m.movie_id)
        FROM    dbo.movies AS m
        where   movie_id in (select movie_id from inserted)
    END
```

As far as the duplicate information goes, Aaron is right that this is needlessly redundant and in my experience, this type of thing often gets out of sync.  With such a simple database, the num_rentals column is overkill (to be generous), but your movie database is a contrived example to teach you a concept.  Basically, sometimes you will want calculated values to be easily accessible or filtered on.  Take SO rep for example, I assume they don't recalc that every time they display it.

Comment: Yes the column num_rentals is showing null so I believe you are right.  I was not sure how to set it to zero which I assume is necessary for the adding or subtracting to take place. I appreciate the feedback and assistance.  The DELETE trigger would look much the same as this one?  Change out INSERT for DELETE and change the + to -?

Comment: John how would I go with the first option and set the column to a default of zero?  ALTER TABLE movies ALTER COLUMN num_rentals int NOT NULL;

Comment: First update your table so all nulls are set to 0, then run the alter that you suggested, then add a default of 0 ... with ALTER TABLE dbo.Tmp_movies ADD CONSTRAINT DF_movies_num_rentals DEFAULT 0 FOR num_rentals

Comment: Oh ... and after setting the column to NOT NULL, change isnull(num_rentals,0) to just the column name.

Comment: I don't know how to set the nulls to zero John.  The more I talk about this the dumber I feel.

Comment: update movies set num_rentals=0 where num_rentals is null;
.... I hope you're looking up all this stuff and not just blindly running it.

Comment: I am searching for all of this in my text book but there are few examples on this topic and they are not very similar to my situation.  Thank you for your help!  I am going to try to do some more reading and make due with what I have here.

Comment: I've found some tutorial videos I'm going to watch and supplement those with the tips here and see what I come up with.  I want to understand this so I am capable of doing it in the future rather than simply have this lone answer.  Thanks again to EVERYONE!!

Answer (score -1):

Aaron's frequently upvoted comment suggests that you are doing something unwise.  However, since you are doing what your instructor is specifying, I suggest that you look at a couple of things.

First, will your update query work for the initial rental?  If the initial value is 0 it will.  If the initial value is null it won't.

Second, you might be referencing the wrong table.  The trigger is on customer_rentals but your trigger refers to inserted.  That strikes me as odd.

Just so you know, I was one of those who upvoted Aaron's comment.

Comment: FYI, here is the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) on the `inserted` table

Comment: Dan I appreciate the candor and the assistance.  I am new to this (obviously) so at this point I am simply doing what I am assigned and trying to learn.  I understand that my exercise may seem unwise to seasoned professionals but I please understand I am just beginning so I am being taught basics and sometimes correctness and efficiency are ignored for simplicity's sake.  I am sure that the count problem is due to my column value showing null.  Second, my trigger should reference the table(Movies) with the num_rentals column?

Comment: I was thinking I should track movie_id where it is the PK and that occurs in the customer_rentals table.